# swapExactTokensForETH / swapExactETHForTokens on pancake swap doesnt swap

Tags: ethers.js, pancakeswap

I need to convert some eth to another token in my unit test. I work on alchemy fork and ethers.js.  I am trying to do it using pancake swap:

```
    it("should use pancake swap to get some tokens",
    async () => {
     

      //const prompt = require('prompt-sync')({sigint: true});
      [owner, acc1, acc2] = await ethers.getSigners();
      const addresses = {
        WBNB: "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c",
        router: "0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e",
        target: owner, 
        DAI_TOKEN_ADDRESS: "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F"
      }

      const BNBAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther('100').toHexString();
      const gasPrice = ethers.utils.parseUnits('100', 'gwei');
      const gas = {
        gasPrice: gasPrice,
        gasLimit: 300000
      }

   
    
    
   

      const router = new ethers.Contract( 
        addresses.router,
        [
          'function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
          'function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)'
        ],
        owner
      );
        
      const ethBalanceStart = await provider.getBalance(owner.address);
  
      const tx = await router.swapExactTokensForETH(
        ethers.utils.parseEther('10'),
        0, // min amount out
        [addresses.WBNB, addresses.DAI_TOKEN_ADDRESS],
        addresses.target.address,
        Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10
      );

     /* const tx = await router.swapExactETHForTokens(
          0,
          [addresses.WBNB, addresses.DAI_TOKEN_ADDRESS],
          addresses.target.address,
          Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10, // 10 minutes from now
          {
            ...gas,
            value: BNBAmount
          }
        );
        */
      console.log(`Swapping BNB for tokens...`);
      const receipt = await tx.wait();
      console.log(`Transaction hash: ${receipt.transactionHash}`);
      console.log(receipt);
      const ethBalanceEnd = await provider.getBalance(owner.address);

      console.log("Eth balance before:", ethBalanceStart);
      console.log("Eth balance after:", ethBalanceEnd);
      //
```

The eth balance does not change.  Here is the full console output with  the receipt:

```
Swapping BNB for tokens...
Transaction hash: 0x14be890fb00192a887cbbec8b99642f992d799f20dd7299277a208cb69243113
{
  to: '0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E',
  from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  contractAddress: null,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  gasUsed: BigNumber { value: "22952" },
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  blockHash: '0xf2f55b4a5006e4729160e950dabb600d3b72d436b49001ed28170cb160353099',
  transactionHash: '0x14be890fb00192a887cbbec8b99642f992d799f20dd7299277a208cb69243113',
  logs: [],
  blockNumber: 17593597,
  confirmations: 1,
  cumulativeGasUsed: BigNumber { value: "22952" },
  effectiveGasPrice: BigNumber { value: "33247122540" },
  status: 1,
  type: 2,
  byzantium: true,
  events: []
}
Eth balance before: BigNumber { value: "10000000000000000000000" }
Eth balance after: BigNumber { value: "10000000000000000000000" }
```